# ruby's Net::HTTPResponse attribute 'code' returns string

Tags: ruby

Why is the Net::HTTPResponse attribute 'code' returning a [string](http://devdocs.io/ruby/net/httpresponse)? Coming from other languages this doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is not intended to be used for arithmetic or other similar operations. This is similar to why you would choose a character type column over a numeric type column in a database.

This works with the string methods well too. For example, if you want to check that it’s a 3XX error, you can do `code.start_with?("3")` rather than using < and > operators.

Comment: It also accommodates cases where the code might be `001` or something unusual.

Comment: OK, this makes sense. To do it `code.to_s.start_with("3")` would still be nicer in my view. An error code below 100 should not occur. So integer still seems the better option to me ;) http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml